# Carrusel de HTML con Bootstrap no me quiere funcionar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel, carrusel

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PowerGym</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>


<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>PowerGym</h1>
    </div>

  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

          <div class="item active">
            <img src="gym1.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="gym2.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="gym3.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="gym4.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="main row">
      <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-mg-9 col-lg-9">
        <h3>Articulo</h3>
        <p>Bienvenidos a PowerGym, el mejor gimnasio de tu comunidad ofreciedo los mejores servicios de personal training.</p>

      </article>

      <aside class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-mg-3 col-lg-3">
        <h3>Aside</h3>
        <p>Se ofrecen clases de Aerobics,Karate,Boxeo y mas!!!.</p>
      </aside>
    </section>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="color1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <h2>Información</h2>
        <h4>Horarios:</h4>
        <p>lunes a Viernes de 6.00Am-12M y de 2.30Pm-8.00Pm. </p>
        <p>Sabados de 8.00Am a 12.00M</p>
        <h4>Aerobics</h4>
        <p>De 8.00Am-9.00Am y de 5.30Pm-6.30Pm.</p>
        <h4>Karate</h4>
        <p>De lunes a Jueves de 4.00Pm-5.30pm.</p>
        <h3>Inscripción: 5.000Bs</h3>
        <h3>Mensualidad: 7.000Bs</h3>

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <h2>Cuentas bancarias</h2>
        <h4>Información:</h4>
        <h5>German Hernandez C.I: V. 5.424.186</h5>
        <h5><b>Banesco :</b> N 0134-0443-7044-3301-5455</h5>
        <h5><b>Mercantil :</b> N 0105-0026-5210-2623-7300</h5>
        <h5><b>BOD</b> : N 0116-0421-8900-1666-3500</h5>
        <h5><b>Bco. Vzla :</b> N 0102-0229-9800-0029-3600</h5>
        <h5><b>Bangente :</b> N 0146-0704-8770-4007-4966</h5>

      </div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
      <div class="color1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <h2>Contactanos</h2>
        <h3>Tlf:0424-229.46.03 // 0416-368.03.04 // 0212-422.38.97</h3>
        <h3>Correo: powergym3@hotmail.com</h3>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <p>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011369600471" :><img src="facebook.png"></a>
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com" :><img src="twitter.png"></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com" :><img src="instagram.png"></a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <h2>Columna</h2>
        <p>MUCHO TEXTOOOOOOO PARA RELLENARRRRRRRRRRRR </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



  <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h3>Carlos Hernandez</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>



  <script src="js/jquery.js">
  </script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene un par de errores:

1. `<div class="col-md-12">` Este elemento está huérfano. Para usar elementos tipo `col` en Bootstrap, éstos deben ser hijos inmediatos de elementos tipo `row`. Puedes leer sobre esto en la documentación de Bootstrap [Grid Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)
2. `<div class="item">` La clase que deseas usar es `carousel-item`.

Corrigiendo los errores que te comento, y asumiendo que tus archivos `JS` y `CSS` están bien, debería funcionar.

Dejo un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>PowerGym</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- carousel start -->
  <div class="container justify-content-center">
    <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active"> <!-- la clase es carousel-item -->
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/27/23/00/weight-lifting-1284616_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/16/15/40/dumbbell-3324976_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/21/22/56/naked-1847866_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/04/22/15/fitness-1882721_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- carousel end -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Espero que sea la respuesta que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigooo eres mi heroe :D